# How to properly test bytes32 in Javascript testing

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-test

How do i address the bytes32 testing issue below?  From the code below:

```
coinState = await NewCoin.at(newCoinAddress).getAuthorization(web3.fromAscii("1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J"));
console.log(coinState);
console.log("A+" + web3.toAscii(coinState[1]).toString().trim() + "+");
console.log("B+" + "1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J" + "+");
console.log("C+" + coinState[1] + "+");
console.log("D+" + web3.fromAscii("1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J") + "+");
assert.equal(web3.toAscii(coinState[1]).trim(), "1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J", "authGUID not correct.")
```

generates the output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is implementation of `toAscii` function:

```
var toAscii = function(hex) {
    var str = "";
    var i = 0, l = hex.length;
    if (hex.substring(0, 2) === '0x') {
        i = 2;
    }
    for (; i < l; i+=2) {
        var code = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16);
        str += String.fromCharCode(code);
    }

    return str;
};
```

Result value based on incoming value, if incoming value has type `bytes32`, result value will have length 32, and `0` converts to `\u0000`. That is why you faced with the issue.

There are multiple ways to fix the issue:

1. Replace `\u0000`

   `assert.equal(web3.utils.toAscii(coinState[1]).replace(/\u0000/g, ''), '1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J');`
2. Assert values in hex format (theoretically should work)

   `assert.equal(coinState[1], web3.utils.fromAscii('1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J', 32));`
3. Fix implementation of `toAscii` function

Comment: #1 worked.  
#2 produced same error
#3 not attempted.